# Dns hosting question

Tags: web-hosting, dns

I'm new to dns hosting and I have recently setup google apps for the 'mail.' cname record.

How can I use it to display files on the www URL? ie: 'www.' cname.
Or is it not possible to upload files using dns hosting only?

I also have hosting elsewhere and wanted to know if I could forward the www cname to a subdirectory on that server, but not displaying the subdirectory URL publicly, rather the address bar constantly remains as the dns hosted (original) domain?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is your DNS hosted?

Comment: With the registrar - free dns hosting with AussieHQ

Answer (score 1):

No, you won't be able to host files at your DNS server. It's only meant to point browsers (or whatever else) to a server where the files are hosted.

If you want www.example.com to point to www.domain.com/folder/path then you could use something like [ZoneEdit's webfoward](http://zoneedit.com/webforward.html). It allows you to point any CNAME at a web URL and cloak it so users don't see it. But just a word of warning, I've tried this before and it hasn't always worked. Another option is to run a script (like PHP) that includes the files from the other address, although this could get complicated depending on how many files you're needing to redirect to.